# Magento white screen after applying changes and running deploy command?

Tags: magento2, php

[image: Attached screenshot]
I am new to Magento and I am facing this issue can any guide me? please after running these commands

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

***Then try running:***

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static:content:deploy -f
php bin/magento c:f
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.
shell  in
go to your magento folder.

```
sudo rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*

sudo rm -rf pub/static/*
```

Comment: thanks it worked